# SPARQL Query uptil nth node in the structure

Tags: sparql, rdf, jena, ontology

I have a structure like below and I am trying to write a SPARQL query that could give me the all the CR's uptil nth level,
here you see CR1 has P1 & P2 and CR2 has P2 & P3 CR3 has P3 & P4 so now suppose I am on the node CR1 I would now like to get all the CR until nth level I can get it up to a required level via this SPARQL but I need a generic one where I don't determine the level it just goes until the nth one below gives till CR3[image]

```
select DISTINCT ?s1 ?o3 where { 
    <http://example.com/test#CR1> test:hasPart ?o .    
    ?s test:hasPart ?o  .
    ?s test:hasPart ?o1 .
    ?s1 test:hasPart ?o1 . 
    ?s1 test:hasPart ?o3 . 
}
```

Comment: I did not get what exactly you want, but SPARQL 1.1 provides property paths, e.g. `?s test:hasPart/^test:hasPart ?o.` returns all `cr` nodes directly connect via two outgoing edges to a `p` node. And property path also do support other operators like `?, +, *` - up to two hops can be done via `test:hasPart/test:hasPart?`

Comment: Yes, it was exactly what I needed Thank you.

Comment: Also I am now in a doubt for suppose I need to start from a specific subject and not all ?s I get it only to a single level it doesn't traverse till the last node ...for instance take :cr3 it gives only cr2 but what I need is cr1 and cr2

Comment: for at most 2 hops it should be `select distinct ?o where { :cr3 (test:hasPart/^test:hasPart)/(test:hasPart/^test:hasPart)? ?o. }`